# Docker build error Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm just learning Docker and working with django from last 1 year.
Today I try to work with docker and getting this error.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django<3.2.2

I'm familiar with this error. But with docker i don't know how to solve this.

Dockerfile Configuration:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine


ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1 
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

requirements.txt

```
Django >=3.2.5,<3.2.2
djangorestframework>=3.12.4,<3.9.0
```

[see the error message image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hlxE.png)

can anyone help me how to fixed this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your requirements.txt is wrong

```
Django >=3.2.2,<3.2.5
djangorestframework>=3.9.0,<3.12.4
```